# Override return values of a column in SQLAlchemy; hybrid property or custom type?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would need a very quick advice. I have a table field which can contain NULL, one or more strings, separated by ';'.

At the moment the column is defined in the model as usual:

```
aliases = Column(String(255))
```

I have an hybrid property that splits the strings and returns a list:

```
def my_aliases(self):
    if self.aliases:
        return [i.strip() for i in self.aliases.split(';')]
```

How can change the default behaviour of the model to get rid of the useless 'self.aliases' and always get the list or None of 'self.my_aliases'?

Is it possible to override the attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mapper` or the declarative API you can create a computed attribute in your class.  Options would include:

- An attribute [computed from a query](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html)
- Using a [descriptor](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html?highlight=descriptors#using-descriptors-and-hybrids) to parse/assemble your semicolon-separated list

And I'm assuming here that you don't have the option of changing the fields of your tables.  But if you do, putting lists that you have to parse inside a single column is a "smell".  For example, what happens when your list is too long?  Better to have a separate table for that data and [use a straight-forward join](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#mapping-a-class-against-multiple-tables) to get your aliases list.